# NPE when calling a method which is having getContentResolver().query in Android

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, mediastore

NullPointerException when calling **getPlaylist()** method from another activity in Android.
The method is supposed to get the audio info then return it using **Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore**...**)**

Here are the details.

I'm working on a custom audio player using two activities (AudioPlayerActivity, FileManager).
AudioPlayerActivity gets a list of audio files using FileManager**, then play them.

Here are snippets of them. The following is **AudioPlayerActivity.java**

```java
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> audioList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

mp = new MediaPlayer();
fileManager = new FileManager();

audioList = fileManager.getPlaylist(); // NPE when calling this method!

playAudio(0);
```

and the next is **FileManager.java**, which reads all audio files and store the details(like MP3 ID tags) in ArrayList using **MediaStore** API.

```java
public class FileManager extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // no view. just getting audio files
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> getPlaylist() {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null}

        Log.d("debug", "is cursor?"); // NPE here!

        return list;
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
09-30 11:55:35.265: D/AndroidRuntime(13516): Shutting down VM
09-30 11:55:35.265: W/dalvikvm(13516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d37c08)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516): Process: project.sample.audioplayer, PID: 13516
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{project.sample.audioplayer/project.sample.audioplayer.AudioPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:104)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at project.sample.audioplayer.FileManager.getPlaylist(FileManager.java:35)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at project.sample.audioplayer.AudioPlayerActivity.onCreate(AudioPlayerActivity.java:70)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
09-30 11:55:35.270: E/AndroidRuntime(13516):    ... 11 more
```

It gives **NullPointerException** at line that having **getContentResolver().query()**.

What am I missing? or is it not possible to use Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore...) in a method instead of in **onCreate()** method?

*I'm pretty sure that AudioPlayerAcitivity.java is not the problem as it works when using **File** class instead of MediaStore in FileManger.java.*

Comment: post a complete stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getContentResolver()` needs to be called with proper context.

Instead of extending FileManager from Activity, just pass in the context from the calling activity (AudioPlayerActivity.java), then you can use the context in `Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()...`